# Cannot disable optimizations while compiling runtime

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

When I use VSCODE in my Ubuntu 16.10 to compile my go project, it can't succeed and prompt:

```
compile: cannot disable optimizations while compiling runtime
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

I checked my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {
                "GOPATH":"/home/bill/test/go",
                "GOROOT":"/usr/local/go"
            },
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```

What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to come from the Go compiler due to [this](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/38380) change which fixes [this bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19571)
(the "compile: " prefix is apparently added by vscode).

My take on the reason is as follows:

1. You have Go runtime source code somehow modified since before you started to experience the present problem.
2. An attempt to build your program detects the runtime has changed
   *and needs to be rebuilt as well*—simply because parts of it are included
   into any program built with Go.

As to how to solve this, I have no clean idea.
Supposedly running

```
$ cd /usr/local/go/src
$ ./make.bash
```

should do it.

---

On a side note, you must not set the `GOROOT` env. variable
by hand—please leave it to the Go suite instead; since many versions ago,
it knows its `GOROOT` automatically based on where the `go` binary
is located.